# MD5 hashing with hashlib produces inconsistencies

Tags: python, hash, md5

So I need to compare two large datafile sets, specifically audio files against each other to see if there is an over lap. Each dataset is 50,000+ files. So what I'v done is created a master file list for python to read, then my script opens each file, runs a hash on the file and adds it to a set(). Then I can see if the two sets intersect. Fairly simple although computational time is long but not a concern for this problem.

Now to test my script I decided to copy two folders with audio in them, in two different locations on my local machine and run my script and see if it can pick up on the fact that the two folders are the same. My code:

```
hasher = hashlib.md5()

with open("/Users/tcrha/Desktop/Music/hashmaster.txt") as inFile:
    for line in inFile:
        nline = line.strip('\n')
        print nline 
        with open(nline) as handle:
            buf = handle.read()
            hasher.update(buf)
            print hasher.hexdigest()

with open("/Users/tcrha/Downloads/Music/hashmaster.txt") as inFile:
    for line in inFile:
        nline = line.strip('\n')
        print nline 
        with open(nline) as handle:
            buf = handle.read()
            hasher.update(buf)
            print hasher.hexdigest()
```

Output:

```
/Users/tcrha/Desktop/Music/Voodoo Glow Skulls/Band Geek Mafia/04 They Always Come Back.mp3
61a89ad11775654a0c469973bc3afc4a
/Users/tcrha/Downloads/Music/Voodoo Glow Skulls/Band Geek Mafia/04 They Always Come Back.mp3
ba5cbe0137dcebebd344942196e2fd5a
```

As you can see both hashes are different, even thought they are the same file. Now when I run the MD5 command on each I receive the correct output.

```
MD5 (/Users/tcrha/Desktop/Music/Voodoo Glow Skulls/Band Geek Mafia/04 They Always Come Back.mp3) = 
61a89ad11775654a0c469973bc3afc4a

MD5 (/Users/tcrha/Downloads/Music/Voodoo Glow Skulls/Band Geek Mafia/04 They Always Come Back.mp3) = 
61a89ad11775654a0c469973bc3afc4a
```

Which matches the output from the first block of code in my script. Is there something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You keep updating the same `hasher` in your two blocks.  If you use two distinct `hasher`s I suspect you'll get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining `hasher` once at the top of your program, then using it to hash two files. A `hashlib.md5` instance computes the md5 hash on the stream of **all** bytes that have been given. So for the second file it's returning `hash(file1 + file2)` instead of just `hash(file2)`.

You should be creating a new `hashlib.md5` for each new file you hash.

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing your `hasher` object. You need to create a new one for each file.